# Mac is running out of disk space. How do I find out what consumes my disk space?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, disk-space, macos-catalina

Today I observed that the disk space is low: only 24.6 GB of 499.9 GB are available
[image: Overview]

Then I wanted to know what the reason therefore is, because I don't have some big files on it, which could use the whole disk space. So I clicked on `Manage`:
[image: HDD Management]

Here I don't see some big files, which use the whole disk space. Imho there should be more than 200 GB of free disk space. But some processes (log files?) are using the whole disk space.

How do I find out, which processes/files are using my whole disk space?

I tried to use [this](https://ww.9to5mac.com/2016/07/01/how-to-show-size-folders-finder-list-view-mac/#) to find out which folder is consuming which disk space, but the calculations are not available for every folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have used DaisyDisk quite a bit, it's smart and fast and solid in my experience: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DaisyDisk

Comment: Is the trial useful? Seems that I can't use the trial, because the company firewall is blocking the trial registration process.

Comment: I believe that I ran the trial before buying, yes.  I almost always do on something like that.  I think it's just time limited, so it works fine and then locks up after some period maybe?  Sorry, don't recall details.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a terminal on your MAC you can make use of the `du` command.

something like the below should give you a list of the biggest files, run it on the /

`du -Sh * |sort -h`